# Shorthand if in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, yii

Shorthand if in a PHP array won't work, even if I surround the true in braces.

The working code:

```
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => [ 
        Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
            ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']] :
            [
                'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
            ],
    ],
]);
```

The not working code:

```
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => [ 
        Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
            (['label' => 'Registrieren', 'url' => ['/site/register']],
            ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']]) :
            [
                'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
            ],
    ],
]);
```

I understand what the problem is, but can't figure out a workarround for it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to have have each part of the code evaluate to something legal - this is not legal:

```
Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
        (['label' => 'Registrieren', 'url' => ['/site/register']],
        ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']])
```

because it would evaluate to

```
['label' => 'Registrieren', 'url' => ['/site/register']],
['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']]
```

that would only be valid if their were another set of `[]` around the whole thing - for example, you could not do:

```
$x = ['label' => 'Registrieren', 'url' => ['/site/register']],
['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']];
```

but you could do

```
$x = [
    ['label' => 'Registrieren', 'url' => ['/site/register']],
    ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']]
];
```

Your code needs to be more like

```
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? 
            [ 
                ['label' => 'Registrieren', 'url' => ['/site/register']],
                ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']]
            ] :
            [
               [
                'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
               ]
            ]
]);
```

Comment: This is correct. Though, I'm sure that most developers will agree that a shorthand like this is pretty hard to understand and should not be used. Defining variables is much more understandable as the array will look much less cramped.

Answer (score -1):

This line looks wrong:

```
(['label' => 'Registrieren', 'url' => ['/site/register']]
```

You have one opening brace '(' but two closing ']' braces, you probably want to remove one of those